# Getting inequality from statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, graph-theory

I have read in book of combinatorics this statement:

> any vertex is incidental with at least four edges, and each edge is incidental with two vertices, so
>   $$ 4 |V| \le 2 |E| $$ where V is set of vertices and E set of edges

I suspect that it is easy but... how I can get this inequality from this statement in formal way, not just write and say "it is obvious because it follows from statement".

> any vertex is incidental with at least four edges

So
$$\forall_v \exists_{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, (e_i \neq e_j)} \forall_{k \in \left\{1,2,3,4 \right\}} v \in e_k$$
 $$|V| \le 4|E|$$

> each edge is incidental with two vertices

$$ |V| = \frac{1}{2}|E|  $$
$$ 2|V| = |E| $$

but I don't get result :( Can somebody explain me, how they get this inequality?

Comment: First of all, you are swapping the coefficients: if every vertex has at least four edges, you should obtain $4|V| \le |E|$. Second, this still ins't correct: every edge touches exactly two vertexes, so we are actually counting every edge twice. In fact, we obtain $4|V| \le 2|E|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us count the elements of the set
$$X=\{\,(v,e)\mid v\in e\,\}$$
in two different ways.

The canonical projection map $\pi_E\colon X\to E$ is 2-to-1. That means that each element of $E$ has *exactly* two pre-images, i.e., $|X|=2|E|$. On the other hand, with the canonical projection map $\pi_V\colon X\to V$, each element of $V$ has *at least* four pre-images. If you don't see immediately that his implies $|X|\ge 4|V|$, pick $4$ pre-images for each $v\in V$ and thereby find a subset $X'\subset X$ such that $\pi_V$ restricted to $X'$ is 4-to-1, hence exactly $|X'|=4|V|$. Putting things together,
$$ 4|V|=|X'|\le |X|=2|E|.$$

Comment: Really great explanation, that helped me a lot, thanks @Hagen!

Answer (score 1):

This is usually called 'double counting' and formally goes like this:

You consider 2 sets of distinct objects, in this case the vertext set $V$ and the edge set $E$ of a graph. You define a relation $R$ between $V$ and $E$ (e.g.  $R \subseteq  V\times E$) that captures the 'interaction' between those 2 sets that you want to look at. In our case that is the incidence relation, that means for $v\in V$ and $e \in E$ we define

$vRe:\iff \text{$v$ and $e$ are incident in the considered graph}$

Less formally, you can imagine creating a bipartite graph with the vertex set $V \cup E$ and the relation $R$ describes the edges that connect certain vertices of $V$ with certain vertices of $E$.

'Double counting' now means to count the number of elements in the relation $R$ in 2 ways: First, for each element $v \in V$, find statements that describe how many $e \in E$ exists with $vRe$. Then for each element $e \in E$, find statements that describe how many $v \in V$ exists with $vRe$. Since

$$|R|=\sum_{v\in V}|\{e\in E:vRe\}| = \sum_{e\in E}|\{v\in v:vRe\}|$$

you get insights if you have formulas that describe exactly or with an inequality the sets in the above equation.

For this problem, the assumption

> any vertex is incidental with at least four edges

translates to

$$\forall v\in V: |\{e\in E:vRe\}| \ge 4$$

and

> each edge is incidental with two vertices

translates to

$$\forall e\in E: |\{v\in V:vRe\}| = 2$$

Thus we get

$$|R|=\sum_{v\in V}|\{e\in E:vRe\}| \ge \sum_{v\in V}4 = 4|V|$$

from the first assumption and

$$|R|=\sum_{e\in E}|\{v\in v:vRe\}| = \sum_{e\in E}2 = 2|E|$$

from the second assumption and finally

$$2|E| = |R| \ge 4|V|$$

---

In this problem one can probably easily see the result without the complicated definitons used above, but if the problems get harder, and the relation $R$ to be used trickier, being able to fall back on this formal construct may help to formally write down knowledge gained and see if it helps to prove the final goal.